# Change value of an observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

In my unit tests I have a method which returns an Observable boolean. I want to change it from true to false, how can I achieve this without using spyOn.

```
// how can I change the value of this observable?
stateService.changeTriggered().subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't *change* the observable per se, you can however use the `pipe` operator to return just about anything you want.

```js
// This will swap the value
stateService.changeTriggered().pipe(map(value => !value)).subscribe();

// This will change it to false
stateService.changeTriggered().pipe(mapTo(false)).subscribe();
```